# Free/total and when free= 10% of total color turns red

Tags: monitoring, snmp, zabbix, prometheus, grafana

I am using Grafana and I am trying to display the values of "Free space/Total size" as actual values rather than calculations. I would like to create a value mapping so that when the free space is 10% of the total size, the color turns red. I am not sure if this is possible, but I believe that the first part should be possible.

Currently, I have the following setup:

[image: free and total sizes image]

I have tried using a transform function, but it gives an odd value and it doesn't seem to have an option for what I need. I only want to see two bars for each datastore, not four. I am a total noob to this whole thing and I can't figure it out.

Should I set an item in Zabbix that shows free/total and visualize it in Grafana instead of trying to find a way to do it in Grafana? Will installing Prometheus help?

Thank you for your help.